# Json Date format to .net DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, json

For the past two hours I tried to convert this /Date(1358805600000)/ to a normal date. Nothing worked.

Comment: there's no such thing as a "json" date. json's just an encoding format. that's a javascript timestamp, which is milliseconds since jan 1/1970. e.g. divide by 1000, and you get a standard unix timestamp.

Comment: I am also dealing with an API that delivers that date format. Does anyone know what kind of format it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-empting Marc B's comment, in an effort to offer an acceptable answer:

There's no such thing as a "json" date. Json's just an encoding format. That's a javascript timestamp, which is milliseconds since jan 1/1970.

Divide by 1000, and you get a standard unix timestamp (which is in seconds).

Answer (score 3):

You can start at the Epoch and add seconds:

```
public static DateTime UnixTimeToDateTime(long UnixTime)
{
   DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0);

   return epoch.AddSeconds(UnixTime).ToLocalTime();
}
```

Note that this does *not* give you a JSON date (whatever that is) but a normal `DateTime` object. You could then use a JSON serializer like [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) to convert this `DateTime` object to a JSON string.

Comment: Yes,I have tried this many times it crushes "Value to add was out of range."

Comment: @user1939553 It is because you have too many zeroes attached to your timestamp. You are probably showing the time not in seconds(which is unixtime).  See here: http://ideone.com/eYGS6U. Also I didn't know what you tried as you didn't post anything.

Comment: To quote Marc B above: *"divide by 1000, and you get a standard unix timestamp"*. That, coupled with the code that has the very telling variable `UnixTime`, one deduces to try to divide your lengthy number by 1000, and then using Hunter McMillen's code sample.